# Varnish. How to redirect based on locale with cookie?

Tags: varnish

I need to implement cookie-based redirection logic for a multilingual site. I have working code for the Next.js middleware, but unfortunately it doesn't work in a standalone setup with Docker (I don't use Vercel).

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export const config = {
    matcher: [
        /*
         * Match all request paths except for the ones starting with:
         * - api (API routes)
         * - _next (static files)
         * - URLs ending with a file extension (e.g., .html, .js, .css, etc.)
         */
        '/((?!api|_next|\\.\\.).+)',
    ],
};

export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
    const { pathname, search, defaultLocale, locale } = request.nextUrl;

    const localeCookie = request.cookies.get('NEXT_LOCALE')?.value;

    if (!localeCookie && locale !== defaultLocale) {
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(`/${defaultLocale}${pathname}${search}`, request.url));
    }

    if (localeCookie && locale !== localeCookie) {
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(`/${localeCookie}${pathname}${search}`, request.url));
    }

    return NextResponse.next();
}
```

Varnish setup I'd like to implement instead of Next.js solution:

```
vcl 4.1;

import cookie;

sub vcl_recv {
    ...

    if (req.url ~ "^/_next" || req.url ~ "/api/" || req.url ~ "/\.(.*)$/") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # Extract the locale from the URL, the default locale is hidden
    if (req.url ~ "^/[a-z]{2}/") {
        set req.http.locale = regsub(req.url, "^/([a-z]{2})(/.*)?$", "\1");
    } else {
        set req.http.locale = "";
    }

    # Extract NEXT_LOCALE cookie
    if (req.http.cookie) {
        cookie.parse(req.http.cookie);
        set req.http.localeCookie = cookie.get("NEXT_LOCALE");
        set req.http.cookie = cookie.get_string();
    }

    // If locale is specified and NEXT_LOCALE is missing, redirect to the default locale.
    if (req.http.locale != "" && !req.http.localeCookie) {
        # set req.http.X-Redirect-Url = ...;
        return (synth(302));
    }
    // If NEXT_LOCALE is present and the locale is not equal to the locale from cookie, then redirect to the cookie locale
    else if (req.http.locale != "" && req.http.locale != req.http.localeCookie) {
        # set req.http.X-Redirect-Url = ...;
        return (synth(302));
    }

    ...

    return (hash);
}

sub vcl_synth {
    # Perform the actual redirection based on the X-Redirect-Url header
    if (resp.status == 302 && req.http.X-Redirect-Url) {
        set resp.http.location = req.http.X-Redirect-Url;
        set resp.reason = "Moved";
        return (deliver);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you able to test and use developer tools to see the responses/headers that are returned to the client in a different locale? That might narrow down which piece of the logic is not working properly.

Comment: After reviewing the question again, I don't actually see the issue. It looks more like you're asking for a code review and on a quick glance it looks like you've commented out the req.http.X-Redirect-Url . Test it and see if it works in a non-production environment.

Comment: thanks! I'll look more into that. just not sure how to properly compose these `X-Redirect-Url` for each condition.

Comment: This VCL code looks pretty good. Glad to see you're using vmod_cookie instead of the ugly regular expressions. The only suggestion I have is to provide a way for users to explicitly use a different locale in the URL without being constantly redirected by the cookie.

Comment: I agree, it was rather strange requirement from the client :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a little help from Chat-GPT for regex, I ended up with a simpler cookie-based redirection logic and default (hidden) locale handling. Thanks for the advice.

```
vcl 4.1;

import std;
import cookie;

...

sub vcl_recv {
    ...

    // Bypass redirection logic for certain request paths
    if (req.url ~ "^/_next" || req.url ~ "/api/" || req.url ~ "/\.(.*)$/") {
        return (pass);
    }

    // Extract the locale from the URL
    if (req.url ~ "^/([a-z]{2})(/|$|\?)") {
        set req.http.X-Request-Locale = regsub(req.url, "^/([a-z]{2})(/|$|\?).*", "\1");
    }

    // Extract NEXT_LOCALE cookie
    if (req.http.cookie) {
        cookie.parse(req.http.cookie);
        set req.http.X-Next-Locale = cookie.get("NEXT_LOCALE");
        set req.http.cookie = cookie.get_string();
    }

    // If X-Next-Locale is `uk` (default) unset it
    if (req.http.X-Next-Locale == "uk") {
        unset req.http.X-Next-Locale;
    }

    // If X-Request-Locale is `uk` perform a 301 (Moved Permanently) redirect
    if (req.http.X-Request-Locale == "uk" && req.http.X-Next-Locale !~ "^(uk|ru)$") {
        set req.http.X-Status-Code = 301;

        // Remove the locale from the URL
        set req.url = regsub(req.url, "^/([a-z]{2})(/|$|\?)", "/\2");

        // Remove double slashes if present in the URL
        set req.url = regsuball(req.url, "//+", "/");

        return (synth(750));
    }

    // Perform a 307 (Temporary Redirect) redirect to X-Next-Locale (cookie locale) if:
    // X-Next-Locale is within existing locales and
    // X-Request-Locale is within existing locales or is missing and
    // X-Request-Locale (url locale) does not match X-Next-Locale (cookie locale)
    if (
        (req.http.X-Next-Locale ~ "^(uk|ru)$") &&
        (req.http.X-Request-Locale ~ "^(uk|ru)$" || !req.http.X-Request-Locale) &&
        (req.http.X-Next-Locale != req.http.X-Request-Locale)
    ) {
        set req.http.X-Status-Code = 307;

        if (req.url !~ "^/([a-z]{2})(/|$|\?)") {
            // If the URL doesn't contain a locale, add the X-Next-Locale to it
            set req.url = "/" + req.http.X-Next-Locale + req.url;
        } else {
            // If the URL already contains a locale, update it with X-Next-Locale
            set req.url = regsub(req.url, "^/([a-z]{2})(/|$|\?)", "/" + req.http.X-Next-Locale + "\2");
        }

        // Remove double slashes if present in the URL
        set req.url = regsuball(req.url, "//+", "/");

        return (synth(750));
    }

    // Remove any cookies left
    unset req.http.Cookie;

    return (hash);
}

sub vcl_synth {
    // Modify response status and location header for redirects
    if (resp.status == 750) {
        set resp.status = std.integer(req.http.X-Status-Code);
        set resp.http.location = "https://" + req.http.Host + req.url;
        set resp.reason = "Moved";
        return (deliver);
    }
}
```

P.S. Don't forget to bypass redirects for bot user-agents.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested in the original question, "force" redirect to the default locale, regardless of the request locale, unless the cookie is set:

```
vcl 4.1;

import std;
import cookie;

sub vcl_recv {
    ...

    // Bypass redirection logic for certain request paths
    if (req.url ~ "^/_next" || req.url ~ "/api/" || req.url ~ "/\.(.*)$/") {
        return (pass);
    }

    // Extract the locale from the URL
    if (req.url ~ "^/([a-z]{2})(/|$|\?)") {
        set req.http.X-Request-Locale = regsub(req.url, "^/([a-z]{2})(/|$|\?).*", "\1");
    }

    // Extract NEXT_LOCALE cookie
    if (req.http.cookie) {
        cookie.parse(req.http.cookie);
        set req.http.X-Next-Locale = cookie.get("NEXT_LOCALE");
        set req.http.cookie = cookie.get_string();
    }

    // If X-Next-Locale is `uk` (default) unset it
    if (req.http.X-Next-Locale == "uk") {
        unset req.http.X-Next-Locale;
    }

    // If X-Next-Locale is not present and request locale is `uk` (default) perform a 301 (Moved Permanently) redirect
    if (req.http.X-Next-Locale !~ "^(uk|ru)$" && req.http.X-Request-Locale == "uk") {
        set req.http.X-Status-Code = 301;

        // Remove the locale from the URL
        set req.url = regsub(req.url, "^/([a-z]{2})(/|$|\?)", "/\2");

        // Remove double slashes if present in the URL
        set req.url = regsuball(req.url, "//+", "/");

        return (synth(750));
    }

    // If X-Request-Locale is within existing locales or X-Next-Locale is within existing locales and X-Request-Locale is missing and
    // X-Request-Locale (url locale) does not match X-Next-Locale (cookie locale)
    // redirect to X-Next-Locale (cookie) if present, or to the default locale if absent
    if (
        (req.http.X-Request-Locale ~ "^(uk|ru)$" || (req.http.X-Next-Locale ~ "^(uk|ru)$" && !req.http.X-Request-Locale)) &&
        (req.http.X-Next-Locale != req.http.X-Request-Locale)
    ) {
        // Perform a 307 (Temporary Redirect)
        set req.http.X-Status-Code = 307;

        // If the URL doesn't contain a locale, add the X-Next-Locale to it (the default locale is empty)
        if (req.url !~ "^/([a-z]{2})(/|$|\?)") {
            set req.url = "/" + req.http.X-Next-Locale + req.url;
        }
        // If the URL already contains a locale, update it with X-Next-Locale
        else {
            set req.url = regsub(req.url, "^/([a-z]{2})(/|$|\?)", "/" + req.http.X-Next-Locale + "\2");
        }

        // Remove double slashes if present in the URL
        set req.url = regsuball(req.url, "//+", "/");

        return (synth(750));
    }

    // Remove any cookies left
    unset req.http.Cookie;

    return (hash);
}

sub vcl_synth {
    ...
}
```